# How to generated dynamic tables using Jaspersoft

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using jaspersoft from couple of days, I have learnt how to create a table with the help of fields from the database, but my requirement is little different. My columns in the table will generate dynamically at runtime depending on some condition in the code. 
For Instance the table could be generated having 3columns or 2columns or 5columns, And there are around 64 combinations of such kind. Hence I cannot predict the fields and number columns till code is compiled and executed. However now I need to display these dynamically generated fields in pdf. Since I am using Jaspersoft I would like to continue doing this task with it.
Please help me if there is way to figure out to create Dynamic columns in the table

Comment: You can use Java + [JasperReports API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/) or [DynamicJasper API](http://dynamicjasper.com/docs/current/apidocs/) or [DynamicReports API](http://apidocs.dynamicreports.org/)

Comment: There are a lot of samples for all this API

Comment: You can also use crosstab passing a custom datasource as "code is executed"  the advantage of crosstabs is that you reamain inside the iReport/JasperStudio Soft IDE

Answer (score 0):

From Java, send the Column Titles als Parameters to the Report, empty String ("") when not to be displayed. Set a Print-When-Expression on every Cell(!!) of the Column Header like this:
LEN(TRIM(${COLUMN_PAR})) > 0

Knowledge of the JasperReports API is crucial.

Comment: Sorry but don't really understand, the column will not be displayed, but it remains... don't you think crosstabs are better?